# Problem adjusting to different screen sizes

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, pivot

I have a problem to adjust some UI-text between iPhoneX and iPad (gen 5 testing).

All except some text works. I think I have tried all kinds of different setups but still do not succeed. The number boxes, in screenshot, have it's markers in the four corners. I think you can see what is missing. I have googled etc. and would appreciate some tip's for this.

Screenshot 1, iPhoneX:
[image]

Screenshot 2: iPad Gen 5:
[image]

Screenshot 3: 
Changed with or height in Canvas, changed the left marker to upper left corned and the other on right-upper corner and got this result:

[image]

Didn't manage to get the titles aligned so I guess I have to live with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try set the canvas scaler -> UI scale mode to scale with screen size

Comment: That was the first thing I did I am afraid.

Comment: I just saw that I missed the reference resolution, will try that.

Comment: Still same problem after correct reference resolution.

Comment: Edited my question with latest status.